# how to convert ascii encoding file to utf-8 encoding in perl?

Tags: shell, file, perl, utf-8, ascii

I want to convert a text file with ascii encoding to utf-8 encoding.
So far I have tried this:

```
open( my $test, ">:encoding(utf-8)", $test_file ) or die("Error: Could not open file!\n");
```

and ran the below command which is showing the encoding of file

```
file $test_file
test_file: ASCII text
```

Please let me know if I am missing something here.

Comment: Did you write anything to the test file? The `file` command determines the file type by looking at the content of the file

Comment: @HåkonHægland yes I am adding some content to the file after opening it. how can we change the encoding of content.

Comment: Please show an example of the content you add. For example, if you add only ASCII characters, there is no difference between UTF-8 and ASCII and `file` cannot determine the difference

Comment: You're doing it correctly. ASCII is a subset of UTF-8, so `file` reports ASCII if you only use that subset.

Answer (score 5):

Any file that is in ASCII (i.e. containing only codepoints from 0 to 127) is already in UTF-8. There will be no difference in encoding and, hence, no way for `file` to identify it as UTF-8.

Differences in encoding only happen with characters with codepoints from 128.

> It was designed for backward compatibility with ASCII: the first 128 characters of Unicode, which correspond one-to-one with ASCII, are encoded using a single byte with the same binary value as ASCII, so that valid ASCII text is valid UTF-8-encoded Unicode as well.
>
> (From the [Wikipedia article on UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8))

Answer (score 3):

You are doing it correctly.

ASCII is a subset of UTF-8.

```
          decode          encode
ASCII       ⇒   Unicode     ⇒   UTF-8
----------      ----------      ----------
00              U+0000          00
01              U+0001          01
02              U+0002          02
⋮               ⋮               ⋮
7E              U+007E          7E
7F              U+007F          7F
----------      ----------      ----------
ASCII       ⇐   Unicode     ⇐   UTF-8
          encode          decode
```

As such, an ASCII file is a UTF-8 file.<sup>[1]</sup>

When you only use that subset, `file` identifies the file as being encoded using ASCII.

```
$ perl -M5.010 -e'use utf8; use open ":std", ":encoding(UTF-8)"; say "abcdef"'  | file -
/dev/stdin: ASCII text
```

Going out of that subset causes `file` to identify the file as text encoded using UTF-8.

```
$ perl -M5.010 -e'use utf8; use open ":std", ":encoding(UTF-8)"; say "abcdéf"' | file -
/dev/stdin: UTF-8 Unicode text
```

---

1. It is also an iso-latin-1 file, iso-latin-2 file, iso-latin-3 file, a cp1250 file, a cp1251 file, a cp1252 file, etc, etc, etc